# Write to Disk in Pages

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I am writing to a disk some text as bytes. I need to maximize my performance and write as complete pages.

Does anybody know what is the optimal size of a page in bytes when writing to disk?

Comment: The whole point of Java is allowing the programmer to forget about implementation details. If you find the need to do low-level, machine-specific optimisations, Java is not your language.

Comment: Have you completed and profiled your application? Otherwise perhaps this might not be where you program is slow and is premature optimization.

Comment: Actually I want to write to the desk but instead of writing line by line I want to write buffer of bytes. I am just inquiring about the optimal size of this buffer?

Comment: I see a lot a buffer length of 4096 bytes.

Comment: Java has Buffer classes that allow the data to be written only when the buffer is filled. These classes can be used by wrapping your target writer or outputstream class.

Comment: I think 4096 is optimal for writing are you sure its the same for writing case?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

Comment: @jforberg I cannot stress enough how wrong you are. You always need to know machine-specific optimizations, independent of the language. Most performance in java libraries comes from these understandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a BufferedWriter or Buffered streams, you should be good. Java uses a 8K buffer. This should be sufficient for most usage patterns. Is your use case anything specific (like do you have fixed length data that needs to be written and fetched from disk in a single shot) etc which is making you optimize what Java already provides?

Comment: No I just need to write the maximum number of bytes in each shot so that I do not wast IO operations. Are you sure 8k is the optimal?!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#BufferedOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream, int) This lets you specify the buffer size. Tweak the value based on the performance characteristics. However, most file system block size is 4K. So, anything big may result in multiple disk seeks which might be bad. So, figure out what works for you. In my experience though, default is fair.